# SQLLite Issue on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, sqlite

I have built an app to be used in work that worked perfectly on KitKat devices.  However on Lollipop devices when making calls to the database the app is crashing. On debugging this is the error:

```
/com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.alcontrol.atmis.AppName/databases/dbName of size 2097152 due to error -12.
```

What is also strange is that it crashes intermittently (i.e. Attempt 1 does work, Attempt 2 doesn't work)

I am not expecting a solution from the limited information I have given (I am not sure what other information I could put up, the code is thousands of lines long).  But I was hoping someone would know what the error means.  Tried googling but haven't been successful.

Comment: Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056246/android-lollipop-error-null-pointer-exception-while-trying-to-read-phone-contca). It may help you.

Comment: Awesome thanks will give it a go.  Just glanced over it and it looks like the link you sent could resolve it.  Thanks again